# Regular expression to fetch all @ mentioned user data from a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, mention

I have below string. This string having data (@[ID:username__FULLNAME]) of three users mentioned. I want to extract them. I have tried below code but not getting desired results.

```
ID is integer type
username and FULLNAME may contain numbers, letter and all kind of special chars.


$t = 'Hi @[4232:mark__MΛRK ATTLEY] how are you ? 
    Hi @[4232:ryan__RYΛN вυηту] how are you ? 
    Hi @[4232:david__DΛVID शाहिद ] how are you ? 
    ';
```

My PHP CODE:

```
$pattern = "|(?:(@\[[0-9]+:[\s\S(?!\])]+\]*))|";
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $mentionList, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($mentionList);
```

Current Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => @[4232:mark__MÎ›RK ATTLEY] how are you ? 
    Hi @[4232:ryan__RYÎ›N вυηту] how are you ? 
    Hi @[4232:david__DÎ›VID शाहिद] how are you ? 

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => @[4232:mark__MÎ›RK ATTLEY] how are you ? 
    Hi @[4232:ryan__RYÎ›N вυηту] how are you ? 
    Hi @[4232:david__DÎ›VID शाहिद] how are you ? 

        )

)
```

Expected Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => @[4232:mark__MÎ›RK ATTLEY]
            [1] => @[4232:ryan__RYÎ›N вυηту]
            [2] => @[4232:david__DÎ›VID शाहिद ]
        )

)
```

Can someone help me getting the desired results?

Thanks.

Comment: just `\@\[.+?\]`

Comment: @splash58 your regex not working

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/T5Ts0m/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex: `@\[.+\]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5Ts0m/4)) that gets you all you have in `[]` plus the front `@`.

Check this working [php demo](https://3v4l.org/WSvTs)

Comment: It will aso match `@[4232:mark__MΛRK ATTLEY] []` or just `@[]`

Comment: isn't any requirment not to match that, where `@[4232:mark__MΛRK ATTLEY] []` is the username `mark__MΛRK ATTLEY] [` ? maybe it is

Comment: i update the original with @\[.+\] which resolved the [] or @[] issue

Comment: @elegant-user whats about `@[4232:mark__MÎ›RK ATTLEY] i have array[10]` without ungreedy (`?' ) - https://regex101.com/r/T5Ts0m/5

Comment: @anubhava as said, that's not specified in the question, your regex is also not 100% right (see the example with the `] [`). Sure you can improve both of them, but only with more input. As for the expected result seems to be needed just the `@` and what's inside the `[ ]`. Cheers

Comment: @Edwin now the only difference between my expression in comment and yours is question mark whick make my one ungreedy. As a result, my expression matches upto the 1st closing bracket while your one - upto the last. I think the 1st case is more suitiable to don't depend on addissional text content

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex with 3 captured groups:

```
/@\[(\d+):(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h*\]/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hua5qL/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `@`: Match literal `@`
- `\[`: Match literal `[`
- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits and capture it in group #1 for `id`
- `:`:  Match literal `:`
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters and capture it in group #2 for `firstName`
- `\h+`: Match 1 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters and capture it in group #3 for `lastName`
- `\h*`: Match 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `\]`: Match literal `]`

Comment: Although I am getting expected results with your regex but alsi getting some additional data that I don;t need. I see Edwin's regex is perfect for me. TY anyway.

Comment: See my comment on that answer. What is point in having definition of `@[id:firstName lastName]` and allowing just `@[]` as valid input.

Comment: Yup seen. Thanks for pointing out that mistake I replaced * with + to solve

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will give you the exact output you are looking for, but yor regex is a bit too greedy. You can simplify it like this: `(?:@\[[0-9]+.+?])`

This should return the captured groups separately.

Not sure if the anonymous capture group is needed so it could be simplified down to `(@\[[0-9]+.+?])` or possibly even `(@\[.+?])`.